# Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories… Не подгружает Spring Data

Tags: maven, spring-data, repository, lib

Возникла такая проблема, что не подгружается Spring Data в проекте, хотя в либах числится.

[image: Процесс зависает на инициализации репозиториев Spring Data]

Посмотрев в библиотеку ,делаю вывод что проблема скорее всего в 26 строке,но как это решить - пока не догадываюсь.
[image: класс DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы заключается в добавлении в файл конфигурации
spring:
jpa:
open-in-view:true